# Loop inverse of pointer, last character?

Tags: c

I have a problem when it comes to showing a result of a pointer.

I'm trying to show the word and for each time eliminating the last character, that is, what I'm trying to do is the opposite of this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[128] = "Some Text";
    char *p;
    int i =0;

    for (p = str; *p ; p++) {
        printf(" value => %s \n ",p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

outPut

```
 value => Some Text 
  value => ome Text 
  value => me Text 
  value => e Text 
  value =>  Text 
  value => Text 
  value => ext 
  value => xt 
  value => t
```

I'm trying this, but I do not get it

```
value => Some Text 
value => Some Tex
value => Some Te
value => Some T
value => Some 
value => Som
value => So
value => S
```

Comment: Huh?   do not understand.

Comment: that is, for each time, I want to show a character less, until I reach the initial one. I'm trying to get the 2 output I showed.

Comment: you need to nul terminate closer and closer to the start of the string. You're currently printing the offsetted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's code changes the string's beginning by adjusting where the string starts (`p++` in the for loop). To change the ending of the string we instead adjust where the string ends by overwriting the last character with a NUL (0) byte. We achieve this by moving an index (`i`) from the end of the string (`strlen(str)`) towards the beginning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[128] = "Some Text";
    char *p;
    int i;

    for (i = strlen(str); i>0; i--) {
        str[i] = 0;
        printf(" value => %s \n ",str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid things like `-->`

Comment: Erik Elmgren can you  only work with the pointers * p without using str (in the for and inside the for), I mention it because my str is of type char * argv []

Comment: @Piedmon, if you need to leave str[] unchanged you can use @abelenky's answer or add to mine a copy of the string to temporary memory with:

 `int len = strlen(str);
 char* tempstr = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
 strlcpy(tempstr,str,len + 1);

 ...

  free(tempstr);`

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is remove the space character after the newline character in the format string.

```
    printf(" value => %s \n",p);
```

The next thing you need to do is keep moving the terminating null character. For that, you need to store a pointer that points to the terminating null character.

Here's an updated version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[128] = "Some Text";
    char *p = str;
    char *end = str + strlen(str);

    // The *(--end) = '\0' is the crucial part.
    // It decrements end so it points to the previous character
    // and changes its value to the null character.
    for ( ; end > p; *(--end) = '\0')
    {
       printf(" value => %s \n",p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

> Can you put any example with the typical "for" with index?

Sure.

Here's one that a little bit more simplified than the first one.

```
for ( ; end > p; --end)
{
   *end = '\0';
   printf(" value => %s \n",p);
}
```

Here's one that uses a "typical" `for` loop.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
   p[len-i] = '\0';
   printf(" value => %s \n",p);
}
```

Comment: Can you put any example with the typical "for" with index?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution, using a bit of a different technique:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[128] = "Some Text";
    int i = strlen(str) + 1 ;

    while( i --> 1 ) {
        printf("value => %.*s \n", i, str );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you print without %.*s ? I need assign this str in a char *var[]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Using the formatter `%.*s` is fine for any char-array or char-pointer.